# Ruby/Rails - Working with both ruby-mysql and mysql2

Tags: compatibility, ruby-on-rails-2, ruby-1.9.2, mysql2, code-migration

I'm migrating a very big Rails 2.3 application from ruby 1.8 to 1.9. Along the way, I've had some database encoding issues that, it seemed, could only be resolved by moving from the old `ruby-mysql` gem to `mysql2`.

This has worked fine for all `ActiveRecord::Base` ORM like queries (`@users = User.find(:all, :conditions => {...})`, etc), but the application also relies heavily on querying the DB directly for some performance related issues. It's quite common to see stuff like this:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(optimized_sql).each_hash do |row|
  # do some stuff with row
end
```

**OR**

```
# for specific connections (different servers, etc)
client = Mysql.real_connect(host, username, password, schema)
client.query(tweaked_sql).each_hash do |row|
  # do some stuff with row
end
```

**OR**

```
# for batch inserts
client.autocommit(false)
insert_list.each { |insert| client.query(insert) }
client.commit
```

I should note that this querying is done mostly in designated class files written for that, so not in controllers, models and such - but mostly for stuff under `app_root/lib/`. I also cannot seem to find many equivalent features of stuff I used in the old gem. A good example is the `#autocommit` like method (to enable batch queries, like multiple INSERTs).

I would like to smooth the transition by using both gems - `mysql2` for all `ActiveRecord` stuff, and `ruby-mysql` for direct client connection to the database. However, when I include both in my app's Gemfile, Rails seems to default to one or the other. Is there a way to configure the Gemfile to only include `ruby-mysql` but not automatically require it when the app loads?

How can I make sure both are present, and only use `require 'mysql'` in the files where I strictly want to use the old gem? Is there any other approach I should be taking? Converting the entire app in one stroke from is a pretty big risk, and I would like to enable my team some time to adapt and transition old code from Mysql to Mysql2.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Although rails isn't really made for that, you definitely can

http://robbyonrails.com/articles/2007/10/05/multiple-database-connections-in-ruby-on-rails